# EditText and ListView are not working together

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am having a weird problem where I have added an `EditText` inside a `ListView` and it is not clickable. When I do `setFocusable:true` in the `EditText` xml it is working but then the `ListView` items are not clickable. I have tried using `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` , `blocksDescendants` and `beforeDescendants`, but [I read](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414) that these solutions works only for `TextView` and checkbox.
Can somebody help to make both the things work together?

Comment: setFocusable:false on EditText. Also you need to manually save the value of each EditText in some array to preserve the UI state.

Comment: have you tried looking into view holder

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The requirement is that in the list view , suppose that i have two rows, then when i enter some number in one row of the edittext, the other row edittext should change accordingly... but he first thing is both listview item and edittext should be clickable

Comment: Why not use ScrollView that hold LinearLayout that you can inflate a row layout that holds EditText?

Comment: Using a ScrollView instead of a ListView  is not an option

Comment: This link did the work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696631/focus-on-edittext-in-listview-when-block-descendants-android