# Edit text not editable android

Tags: android

I have an Edit Text inside a custom `ListView`. When I am typing a value in the `EditText`, it is not showing what I type. If I tap several times on the `EditText`, it appears the typed text sometimes. How should I overcome this issue?

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edtReason"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chkSelect"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView20" />
```

Comment: Please post custom ListView code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Focus on EditText in ListView when block descendants (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696631/focus-on-edittext-in-listview-when-block-descendants-android)

Comment: Basically, the ListView is taking the focus of the click instead of the EditText

Comment: Can you try adding android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to your edit text xml. I believe its a issue with list view. Even if you place a button on listview tapping it is pain :) I had the same issue "android:descendantFocusability" solved my problem :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari That goes on the ListView, not EditText

Comment: I added android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" into my EditText. But nothing changed. Basically I have to type the characters and nothing is showed in the edit text. But once I tap in the EditText, I can see the text.

Comment: please have a look at my answer, if it does not work then post the xml file of the custom layout of your listview item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have added the following property in parent layout of your listview item

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Now add the following in xml of EditText

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: ListView items are inside a RelativeLayout. What you are saying is add android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" into the RelativeLayout ? I tried that, then keyboard is not popping up.

Comment: add  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest file

Comment: This listview is loaded inside a fragment, not inside an Activity. So where do I add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest file? Under <Application>?

Comment: Above worked for me if I add android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" into the ListView. Sorry earlier I thought of adding listview item. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Add these attributes and try again, Hope this helps

```
    android:hint="Enter Message"  
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPostalAddress"     
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"       
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"   
    android:textColor="#44444"
    android:ems="10"
```

Add this in Manifest:

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Manifest

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ListviewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```