# List item click listener inside a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to change the text and check box response of the clicked list item but I am not able to do so. As I not able to get the click list item.
The fragment is a part of view pager.

[image]

Here is my code,

```
public class ParticipantsFragment extends Fragment {

    private ParticipantAdapter mAdapter;
    SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    private String mParticipantId, mEventId, mGender;
    ParticipantsAsyncTask task;


    public ParticipantsFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mEventId = getArguments().getString(Config.BUNDLE_KEY_EVENT_ID);
        mParticipantId = getArguments().getString(Config.BUNDLE_KEY_PARTICIPANT_ID);
        mGender = getArguments().getString(Config.BUNDLE_KEY_GENDER);

        Log.v("fragh", mEventId + " " + mParticipantId);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.participant_list, container, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.no_participant);

        task = new ParticipantsAsyncTask();
        task.execute();

        ListView participantListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.participant_list);
        refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout_participant_list);



        participantListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Log.v("Clicked Participant",mAdapter.getItem(position).getParticipantName());

                EditText notes = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.participant_list_item_notes);
                String text = notes.getText().toString();

                Log.v("Participant Text",text);

                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.participant_list_item_checkbox);
                String check;
                if(checkBox.isChecked())
                {
                    check = "1";
                }
                else
                {
                    check = "0";
                }

            }
        });

        Button submit = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit_participant);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        mAdapter = new ParticipantAdapter(getContext(), new ArrayList<Participant>());

        participantListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        participantListView.setEmptyView(textView);

        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                task = new ParticipantsAsyncTask();
                task.execute();
                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });


        return rootView;

    }

    private class ParticipantsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Participant>> {

        private ProgressDialog progress;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            progress.setMessage("Gathering Data...");
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Participant> data) {

            // Clear the adapter of previous participant data
            mAdapter.clear();

            // If there is a valid list of {@link Event}s, then add them to the adapter's
            // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
            if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
                mAdapter.addAll(data);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Participant> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            List<Participant> result;

            if (!mGender.isEmpty()) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(Config.KEY_EVENT_ID, mEventId);
                map.put(Config.KEY_PARTICIPANT_ID, mParticipantId);
                map.put(Config.KEY_GENDER, mGender);

                result = QueryUtils.extractParticipantData(map, Config.FEVER_GENDER_FILTER_PARTICIPANT_URL);

            } else {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(Config.KEY_EVENT_ID, mEventId);
                map.put(Config.KEY_PARTICIPANT_ID, mParticipantId);
                Log.v("law", mEventId + ", " + mParticipantId);
                result = QueryUtils.extractParticipantData(map, Config.FEVER_ALL_PARTICIPANT_URL);

            }

            progress.dismiss();
            return result;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        mAdapter.clear();
    }
}
```

**participant_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/no_participant"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/no_participant_found"
    android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout_participant_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/participant_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@color/divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit_participant"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**participant_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/participant_list_item_id"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:text="M78" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/participant_list_item_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    tools:text="Billu Barber" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/participant_list_item_notes"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:background="@drawable/participant_list_notes"
    android:hint="@string/participant_notes"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:maxLength="50"
    android:padding="4dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/participant_list_item_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
set this for checkbox in xml

Comment: @user3040153 Thanks for giving time but it isn't working. I tried to it. The box in the left of checkbox is an edittext.

Comment: you can try click of view of row in listview also

Comment: @user3040153 How to do that?

Comment: @RishabhSharma try to click on the person's name to see if the listener gets fired.

Comment: you can take click of parent view defined in listview adapter OnCreateView

Comment: @EduardoHerzer Not working

Comment: @RishabhSharma can you post your xml layout?

Comment: @EduardoHerzer please check it now

Comment: @RishabhSharma try removing the `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` atribute from ListView

Comment: @RishabhSharma if that doesn't work, try removing the `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"`from your **LinearLayout** inside **participant_list_item.xml**

Comment: @EduardoHerzer Sir not working

Comment: @RishabhSharma I'm not sure what's happening in your code. Everything seems ok. Try removing also the `android:clickable="true"`, `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` from  the LinearLayout.

Comment: @EduardoHerzer Tried everything. Nothing is working. I need to do it.

Comment: @EduardoHerzer I have tried some thing. Used android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in participant_list_item.xml LinearLayout. Now I am able to check the clicked list item but not able to update EditText and CheckBox.

Comment: @RishabhSharma I see... maybe the solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20755698/2174489

Comment: @EduardoHerzer Solved. Thank you very much. You saved me.

Comment: @RishabhSharma no problem, glad to help. I've updated my answer with this solution link, if you would like to accept it

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that at the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` you are using `rootView` to access the cell properties. Like:

```
EditText notes = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.participant_list_item_notes);
...
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.participant_list_item_checkbox);
```

You should use the parameter `View view` from `onItemClick` like that:

```
EditText notes = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.participant_list_item_notes);
...
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.participant_list_item_checkbox);
```

Let me know if it solves your problem.

Edit:

If the problem is having the item clicked, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/20755698/2174489